# Specify the assembly explicitly?

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, explicit

I am getting this ambiguous reference error with some software that came from a vendor. The problem is, I need to keep both DLLs in my project, because various parts of it use code from both. So... I need to know the syntax for explicitly specifying the assembly. In other words, I want to do exactly what the error message is telling me to do - but I can't find the syntax for that anywhere. Many people have this problem and Google searches turn up a lot "close VS and re-open the project" or "you need to update" solutions - but I'm not looking for that - I just want to explicitly specify the assembly to use in this one file. I really hate having to fix vendor code. Why is the syntax for this not listed in MSDN anywhere? If you have the link, please post it, I think I've seen it before, but I can't find it now.

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Settings.ascx.vb" 
Inherits="TIMSSCMS.DNN.Modules.CustomerDemographics.Settings" %>
```

The type 'TIMSSCMS.DNN.Modules.CustomerDemographics.Settings' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\EbusMain\bin\AWWA.DNN.Modules.CustomerDemographics.DLL' or from assembly 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\EbusMain\bin\Personify.DNN.Modules.CustomerDemographics.DLL'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
TIMSSCMS.DNN.Modules.CustomerDemographics.Settings, TIMSSCMS.DNN, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, ( PublicKeyToken=...)
```

Comment: Yeah that was it - but it uncovered a deeper problem. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

If the vendor DLLs are strong named, just use the fully qualified assembly name for the "Inherits" value, including the PublicKeyToken.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69(VS.80).aspx)